# import android.app.NotificationChannel error

Tags: android, react-native

I am getting the below error when trying to compile my android React-native app.

```
    :react-native-push-notification:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
/tmp/workspace/my-develop/my_app/node_modules/react-native-push-notification/android/src/main/java/com/dieam/reactnativepushnotification/modules/RNPushNotificationHelper.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
                  ^
  symbol:   class NotificationChannel
  location: package android.app
/tmp/workspace/my-develop/my_app/node_modules/react-native-push-notification/android/src/main/java/com/dieam/reactnativepushnotification/modules/RNPushNotificationHelper.java:480: error: cannot find symbol
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                                                       ^
  symbol:   variable O
  location: class VERSION_CODES
/tmp/workspace/my-develop/my_app/node_modules/react-native-push-notification/android/src/main/java/com/dieam/reactnativepushnotification/modules/RNPushNotificationHelper.java:488: error: cannot find symbol
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
                                            ^
  symbol:   variable IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
  location: class NotificationManager
/tmp/workspace/my-develop/my_app/node_modules/react-native-push-notification/android/src/main/java/com/dieam/reactnativepushnotification/modules/RNPushNotificationHelper.java:489: error: cannot find symbol
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        ^
  symbol:   class NotificationChannel
  location: class RNPushNotificationHelper
/tmp/workspace/my-develop/my_app/node_modules/react-native-push-notification/android/src/main/java/com/dieam/reactnativepushnotification/modules/RNPushNotificationHelper.java:489: error: cannot find symbol
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
                                          ^
  symbol:   class NotificationChannel
  location: class RNPushNotificationHelper
Note: /tmp/workspace/my-develop/my_app/node_modules/react-native-push-notification/android/src/main/java/com/dieam/reactnativepushnotification/helpers/ApplicationBadgeHelper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
5 errors
:react-native-push-notification:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
```

I have read various posts saying that this issue can be resolved by setting `compileSdkVersion 26`. However I already had this set to `26`. I havent seen any other suggestions for what might cause this issue.

Comment: can you specify the android version where you are running this app?

Comment: I cant run the app as I cannot build it.

Answer (score 1):

android/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
}
```

android/app/build.gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
   ...
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    ...
}
```

Inside react-native-push-notification/android/build.gradle

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'  //-----> Changed this from 2.1.3
```

}

```
def DEFAULT_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION = 27
```

def DEFAULT_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION = "27.0.3"

def DEFAULT_TARGET_SDK_VERSION = 26

def DEFAULT_SUPPORT_LIB_VERSION = "26.+"

def DEFAULT_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION = "+"

def DEFAULT_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_VERSION = "+"

Comment: > Inside `react-native-push-notification/android/build.gradle` - wont this get overwritten when I run `npm install`?

Comment: I dont think that is relevant. We are not building on windows.